# Compile time elimination of virtual tables?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

Assuming i have this hierarchy :

```
class Super
{
 public:
    virtual void bar();
};

class Sub : public Super
{
 public:
    virtual void bar() override;
};
```

is there a way for me to avoid vtables despite using the virtual key word? (curiosity) i have read something about a compiler optimization that eliminates vtables when the object is known during compile time, I'm not really sure, been digging around google for a while, but could't find any answers, so does it mean these?

```
Sub sb;
sb.bar(); //avoids vtable?
Super& sr = sb;
sr.bar(); //avoids vtable?
Super* srp = &sb;
srp->bar(); //avoids vtable?
```

Comment: As I know the access via vtable is optimzed away if object is known at compile time. But I have never seen that the vtable itself is removed from the class if it was never used. But if you write your code that you know always which object is used, simply remove the virtual :-)

Comment: By definition, most vtables can't be known at compile time. Google late-binding.

Comment: Yes, the question is somewhat unclear: If you say "avoid vtables", do you mean "bypass an existing vtable" or "avoid creating one"?

Comment: @Leandros Obviously the compiler is free to do early binding if it can prove that that is correct. Which it could, if I'm not mistaken, in all of the three examples given.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider That is true.

Comment: there is a way: not using runtime polymorphism but templates. it may replace virtual functions most of the times, sometimes it doesn't

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider you're right on your last comment. I always had the notion that once a method is declared virtual, a vtable will always be created, so i was thinking that if it was made obvious to the compiler as to what object i am gonna use, it's gonna optimize away.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider I'm not sure about GCC and CLang, but MSVC++ will defenitly won't do it

Comment: @DavidHaim yes, but you see I'm a fresh grad hire and will be assigned with java loving freshies as well. so if i go template-tastic on my code, i might get punched.

Comment: @Epsilon_ if you guys try to bend C++ in being Java, you will just write crappy code. I can't emphasize enough the importance of templates in C++. write good Java in Java, write good C++ in C++. don't try to force the other to be first.

Comment: @DavidHaim i personally favor C++ even before college, however, personally knowing my coworkers' (team) skill sets, i am afraid they wouldn't understand my code, so I'm trying to hold back on the complicated parts.

Comment: So why did anybody give you a C++ project instead of Java one? and more importatnly, why does you team insists of being closed minded? programing is about learning and be skilled as much as possible instead of being a language biggots..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109525/discussion-between-epsilon-and-david-haim).

Comment: @DavidHaim what are your thoughts on putting everything in headers by using policy based class design by templates ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the gcc developers has a whole [series of blog posts about devirtualization](https://hubicka.blogspot.com/2014/01/devirtualization-in-c-part-1.html). I think he is also active on SO, so there may be a chance that he responses.

However, devirtualization deals mostly with eliminating virtual dispatch by analyzing the program flow and possible types. I don't think it removes the virtual table in general, but there is an example in the second article where a virtual gets inlined and can then be evaluated completely at compile time through constant propagation. In that case, the compiler/linker transformed the program to not use the class at all, and thus it should not contain any object or vtable.

Comment: That is a nice explanation. If the function source is visible a lot of optimizations become possible, including just inlining everything.

Answer (score 3):

```
Sub sb;
sb.bar(); //avoids vtable?
```

The above will never need to use a vtable for dispatch, as the runtime type is known (i.e. it's known to be the same as the compile-time/static type, namely `Sub`).

```
Super& sr = sb;
sr.bar(); //avoids vtable?


Super* srp = &sb;
srp->bar(); //avoids vtable?
```

In these cases, if the pointer/reference and usage appear in the same function, the optimiser may well be smart enough to avoid dispatch via a vtable.  If the pointer or reference is passed to some other out-of-line function that migth be called with other types of pointers, then vtable-based dispatch will normally be needed.

More generally, the C++ Standard doesn't make any stipulations about how runtime polymorphism is implemented, so there is no guaranteed, portable way to eliminate "vtables".

That said, your best bets to minimise use of the vtable for dispatch are:

- to mark overrides [`final`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final) when the freedom to override further is not actually required, and
- to keep the implementation inline (even if implicitly - by having the function implementation in the class definition)

To see if either/both help, you'll have to experiment with or read the docs for your own compiler / tool-chain, optimisation flags etc..

An unused vtable may or may not be removed by the linker: you may want to experiment with cross-object linker optimisation flags if you have multiple translation units.